# How to run a query for a map job only in Apache hive

Tags: hive

If I write a query in Apache hive then it executes mapreduce job behind the scene but how I can run only map job in hive?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Friend, send more detail of your requirement, what you want to do in that Map Job?

Comment: Normally once we write query in hive like Select * from tweets where Location=UK; then it runs map and reduce both job. I just need to know what is the way to run Map job only through SQL Statement?

Answer (score 0):

Certain optimized queries do in fact only require a map phase. You may provide a **MAPJOIN** hint in Hive to achieve same: this is recommended for small secondary tables:

```
 SELECT /*+ MAPJOIN(...) */ * FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a question which was asked to me in an interview,I didn't knew the answer that time but then i figured it out later on.

The following query runs a Map only job.So selecting column values will run map only job.Hence we dont need reducer for this scenario.

```
  select id,salary from tableA;
```